# как добавить в .mkv ass сабы?

Tags: ffmpeg

исходный файл с дополнительными дорожками и какимито сабами
я нашел в доке такую команду:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" out.avi
```

но на выходе я получаю файл без доп дорожек и без сабов(может с хардсабами я хз)

подаю вот это

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Ghostwithrus.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 01:22:52.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16104 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le, 1856x1004, SAR 1:1 DAR 464:251, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Koukaku Kidoutai - Ghost in the Shell
      LANGUAGE        : jpn
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : 2.0 FLAC
      LANGUAGE        : jpn
    Stream #0:2(rus): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : AC3 2.0 (╨Я╨╛╨╗╨╜╨╛╨╡ ╨┤╤Г╨▒╨╗╨╕╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜╨╕╨╡, ╨Я╨╡╤А╨▓╤Л╨╣ ╨Ъ╨░╨╜╨░╨╗)
      LANGUAGE        : rus
Input #1, ass, from 'rus.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Subtitle: ass
```

а выходит уже такое

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'Ghost in the Shell (1995)_rus_rus_subs.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p10le, 1856x1004 [SAR 1:1 DAR 464:251], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Koukaku Kidoutai - Ghost in the Shell
      LANGUAGE        : jpn
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: flac ([172][241][0][0] / 0xF1AC), 48000 Hz, stereo (16 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : 2.0 FLAC
      LANGUAGE        : jpn
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.56.101 ass
```

куда пропадает аудиодорожка?
какой командой можно запихать в файл сабы и не потерять то что там уже есть?

Comment: не помещайте ответ в вопрос. Если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ -- это [явно поощряется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ffmpeg -i source.mkv -i subs.ass   -map 0 -map 1 -c copy "output.mkv"`**